# POST and GET on NODE JS, tried everything

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I created a login where there is a GET form and in the server code there is:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I can't manage to insert a POST, because if I put "POST" I get "CANNOT / POST" if instead I put "get" I get "CANNOT GET" :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juzds.png)

how can I do?

I need this page to be POST

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.get("/chat", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("/path/to/chat.html");
});
```